# Replace em dashes in all elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is how I create an array by splitting each line. Also I'm trying to remove all empty lines/elements.

```
var result = string.split('\n').filter(v => v !== '');
```

Additionally I would like to replace all em dashes with 'normal' dashes. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = string.split('\n')
    .filter(v => v !== '')
    .map(v => v.replace(/\u2014/g, '-'))
```

Comment: That's no em dash, isn't it?

Comment: While you can just shove `—` into the regex without issue, I feel it's potentially ambiguous. The regex `/\u2014/` is much clearer which character you're trying to get, and of course a good old comment `// replace em-dash with hyphen` wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: If you copy paste an actual em dash like found on this page: http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html  it will work without unicode. It might be surprising to future readers of the code though!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You are right, will edit the answer.